# Download big files from ESXi?

Tags: ssh, virtualization, vmware-esxi, scp, copying

I want to move one of my vm guest between two ESXi servers. I can't do this with converter or Veaam FastSCP because I'm in another network and using this tools is extremly slow. So I'm trying to copy  files from one scp to one of servers in the same network using ssh and than send this file with ssh to second ESXi. I was trying to use scp(scp from esxi to server) on hole directory (recursively) with my vm guest but it hangs and do nothing. So I used mc to connect to esxi and download files after file. That goes quite well with small files. When I'm trying to download guest-flat.vmdk (16GB) I get error that file on remote host couldn't be read.

The guest vm is off. What could be the problem. How to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Add a NFS volume (e.g. exported from an utility host) to (both/all) of your ESXi servers, then copy the files within ESXi from one volume to the other.

As a side effect, you will have a backup on the NFS host.

Or, you can run the VM from the NFS volume on any connected ESXi host.

Comment: Personally I would recommend running the machines from NFS unless the disk latency gets to be a problem.

Comment: even copying from a machine on the local gigabit network is horribly slow (says 996 minutes remaining... for 24GB = 0.5 MB/s :D wtf ESXi.... (60 GB sparse = 1.25 MB/s)) but this NFS thing is fast enough (maybe 22 min for 15GB = 11 MB/s (60 GB sparse = 45 MB/s)), so thanks for the idea

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a simpler solution:
Install vSphere client on a (virtual) machine in the remote network and use it over some kind of remote desktop connection like VNC.